# What date range must I use for a daily report?

Tags: bash, log

I want to run a report at 6am every morning that includes the log entries of the last 24 hours. Do I run the report from:

2013-08-31 06:00:00 till 2013-09-01 06:00:00

or

2013-08-31 06:00:00 till 2013-09-01 05:59:59

Answer (score 0):

You would search for log entries **greater than or equal to** yesterday 6am and **less than** today 6am. Then you won't miss/repeat any entries.